# using str_replace with file_get_contents

Tags: php

I am using file_get_contents to grab a page, but i need to replace some data in the contents of the page before echoing it.

I have this so far (this script runs on domain2.com)

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/page.html');
str_replace('href="/','href="http://domain.com','$page');
echo $page;
?>
```

The problem is, that when the page displays, some links on the domain.com page read:

```
<a href=/about.html>
```

Which when i call in my script, are prepending it with the incorrect domain. I tried using str_replace, to look for

```
href="/
```

and replace it with

```
href="http://www.domain.com/
```

But its not working. Any clues?

Comment: I deleted my answer because there would be a ton of problems with it if executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed it

```
$pagefixed = str_replace("href=\"/","href=\"http://www.domain.com/","$page");
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

You'll either need to use a regular expression (preg_replace) or 2 str_replaces since quotes vary.